# Find significant change in sensor data

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, change-point, quality-control

I have a sensor, which produces normal distributed data under usual conditions. If there is some defect the values will increase for a certain timespan.

[image]

I want to detect such a change using a significance test, but I am not sure which one is appropriate. Can I apply a t-test here? Ideally I also want to specify the difference between the two cases, e.g. "show me all 1h-timespans, where the mean differs significally at least 20% from the overall mean?

Thanks for any hints

Comment: A common approach is use a forecasting model like Holt-Winters on data without a defect. The forecast errors will have a certain distribution. Once a defect occurs, the forecast errors will be very big. You can find a cutoff for a single or cumulative sum of errors easily. Formal testing then is not involved, except for observing that the error has a very high standard deviation.

Comment: is a significance-based approach valid? like t-test or SPRT?

Comment: SPRT: 'The model aims to determine the quality of a batch of products by minimal sampling. The idea is to sample the batch sequentially until a decision can be made whether the batch conforms to specification and can be accepted or that it should be rejected.' This seems different from your objective, but I'm not familiar as such. Your objective is not so much significance, but deviation. Testing against the distribution of errors seems valid.